# Использование квадратных скобок в регулярных выражения в С++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex exp("[+-*]");
    smatch res;
    string str = "+b-b*";

    while (regex_search(str, res, exp)) {
        cout << res[0] << endl;
        str = res.suffix();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Как только добавляю в квадратные скобки знак умножения происходит сбой в работе программы. Мне необходимо найти знак плюс, минус и умножения.

Comment: Экранирование символов

Answer (score 0):

Экранируйте спецсимволы: `[\+\-\*]`

Comment: Не помогает. Пробовал в VS 2017 и в CodeBlock. Везде сбой.

Answer (score 0):

```
regex exp("[*+-]");
```

Все сработало, как только знак умножения поставил самым первым внутри квадратных скобок. Странно конечно.